# how to write a web browser from stratch use c

Tags: c, browser

These days I'm aware of the powerful web browser. In order to know what happend behind the screen. I want to write a simple web browser. But When I try to find  document about that. Nothing find! Any one konw how to write a simple web browser or know where is the book will be useful. Please tell me !

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

Start off with a simple browser -- e.g., look at existing text only ones like `lynx` or `w3m`. Once you've got them cracked, then you can work up to adding graphical elements. It can get complicated fairly quickly, so make sure you've read the appropriate RFCs for HTTP and the W3C standards as well. These aren't light reading material though :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to get you started:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Download_Mozilla_Source_Code

C might not be the best language for this job.

Comment: He said he wants to make a *simple* browser. I think [Lynx](ftp://artfiles.org/lynx.isc.org/lynx2.8.7/lynx2.8.7rel.1.tar.bz2) or [Links](http://www.jikos.cz/~mikulas/links/download/links-1.02.tar.gz) would be a better choice

Comment: @wormsparty I've never heard of them, but they're obviously the better choice in this case. :) Thanks.

Comment: @wormsparty: +1 -- I couldn't live without `lynx` (or preferably `elinks`). It's still one of my overall top-utility browsers! (Arguably right after `wget`, though perhaps that doesn't qualify as a "browser".)